# How to plot part of date time in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have massive data from CSV which spans every hour for a whole year. It has not been difficult plotting the whole data (or specific data) through the whole year.

However, I would like to take a closer look at month (for ex just plot January or February), and for the life of me, I haven't found out how to do that.

```py
   Date                   Company1       Company2
2020-01-01 00:00:00        100            200
2020-01-01 01:00:00        110            180
2020-01-01 02:00:00        90             210
2020-01-01 03:00:00        100            200
      ....                 ...            ...
2020-12-31 21:00:00        100            200
2020-12-31 22:00:00        80             230
2020-12-31 23:00:00        120            220
```

All of the columns are correctly formatted, the datetime is correctly formatted. How can I slice or define exactly the period I want to plot?

Comment: I think you can set [`xlim`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) for pandas plot, assuming that you have x-axis ad `Date`

Comment: Refere [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250467/plot-certain-days-only-pandas-dataframe) , [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66968915/how-can-i-plot-only-the-month-and-the-day-without-the-year-from-this-pandas-da)

Comment: @WakemeUpNow xlim did the trick, I just hadn't thought about it. Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the month portion of a pandas datetime using `.dt.month` on a datetime series. Then check if that is equal to the month in question:

```py
df_january = df[df['Date'].dt.month == 1]
```

You can then plot using your df_january dataframe. **N.B.** this will pick up data from other years as well if your dataset expanded to cover other years.

Comment: Thank you for this, found out that xlim in pandas.DateFrame.plot actually does the trick. Using datetime also seems to mess something up.

Answer (score 0):

@WakemeUpNow had the solution I hadn't noticed. defining `xlin` while plotting did the trick.

```py
df.DateTime.plot(x='Date', y='Company', xlim=('2020-01-01 00:00:00 ', '2020-12-31 23:00:00'))
plt.show()
```